# Do we need to staple non-metallic cables near box when there is a nearby hole in stud? (BC, Canada)

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I wish to extend an outlet with another run of cable (14/2). I have a horizontal run of cable to make along the wall, and the stud closest to the outlet will be bored less than 30mm away from the existing box (shown by green X), just above the box. Do I need to add a cable staple between the hole and the box, or is the hole considered sufficient?

I've included a copy of the relevant section of my electrical code (BC electrical code 2015) . I'm not sure if bullet (2) takes precedence over the listing of acceptable supports in bullet (4).

[image: my situation]
[image: bc electrical code 2015]

Comment: I'm no code expert, but my interpretation is that `2)` says that a hole is considered to be a support. Therefore, I'd suggest that a hole within 300mm of where it exits the box meets both `1a)` and `4)`. Again, not an electrician and certainly not a code expert.

Comment: That doesn't look like typical NM 14/2 cable to me. Are you sure it is the right stuff?

Comment: The existing cable you see (running vertically) is Southwire "Romex" 14/2. I have noticed that in the canadian version of this cable, the center part is concave -- the bare copper is in the center. I've seen other versions of the same cable where the whole sheath is convex (cable looks flat). Maybe that's what is catching your eye? I actually prefer it with the recessed center, it's easier to split: you don't need as much skill when running a knife down the center to separate black from white wires.

[example product page](https://a.co/d/iNqiwlN)

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact

Comment: Aha! That would definitely explain it. I was worried somebody had tried to sneak some lamp cord or other totally wrong stuff into the wall.

Comment: @FreeMan Thanks. That's a fair interpretation. The main reason I hesitate is that (4) explicitly goes through the list of permissible supports again, as opposed to just saying "cable needs to be supported", but I'm probably overthinking this.

Comment: Wouldn't the point in #4 "... supported by straps, Type 25 or 215 cable ties, or other devices located within 300mm of the switch ..." include studs and an "other device" considering that #2 clearly defines "Cables run through holes in joists or studs are considered to be supported"?

Comment: For future reference, the screen shot of code requirements is good. Copy/pasting actual text would be _great_. It would have saved me having to retype bits because I could have copied from your question, instead.

Answer (score 3):

I'm no code expert, but my interpretation is that:

The two support sections in question are:

- `1a)` (the cable should be supported) "within 300 mm of every box fitting..."
- `4)` explicitly states that it must be supported by "...or other devices located within 300 mm of the switch or wall opening...".

Since `2)` explicitly states that

> Cables that run through holes in joists or studs shall be considered to be supported

It seems that a hole is considered a support that qualifies for meeting both `1a)` and `4)`

Again, not an electrician and certainly not a code expert. When in doubt consult with your local inspector.

Answer (score 2):

Ah I actually stumbled upon the answer later on, accidentally by searching the code for something else...

> 70-114 Wiring methods — General
> ...
> (4) Cable run through holes in joists or studs shall be considered to be
> secured for the purposes of Rules 12-510 and 12-618.
> ...

[image: Code]

**Canadian Electrical Code 2015, Section 70**